# Flask: form.validate_on_submit() throwing type error

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

Everytime I submit my form on '/signup' view, `form.validate_on_submit()` in my `views.py` throws the error below:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

The stack trace is pretty long and I don't see anything immediately obvious. I have no idea why it is doing this. I followed the [Flask-WTF docs](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html) for validating forms.

EDIT: [Here](https://pastebin.com/vWUeHWSd) is the stack trace I am seeing.

#### views.py

```
from myapp import app
from flask import render_template, redirect
from forms import RegistrationForm

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@app.route('/signup', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def signup():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # Redirect to Dash Board
        return redirect('/dashboard')
    return render_template("signup.html", form=form)

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    return "<h1>Login</h1>"

@app.route('/dashboard')
def dashboard():
    return "<h1>Dashboard</h1>"
```

#### forms.py

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import TextField, PasswordField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Email, Length

class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = TextField('username', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=30)])
    email = TextField('email', validators=[InputRequired(), Email, Length(max=25)])
    password = PasswordField('password', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=8, max=80)])

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = TextField('username', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=30)])
    password = PasswordField('password', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=8, max=80)])
```

#### signup.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Sign Up</h1>

<form method="POST" action="/signup">
{{ form.hidden_tag() }}
<p>Username:</p>
{{ form.username() }}
<p>Email:</p>
{{ form.email() }}
<p>Password:</p>
{{ form.password() }}
<br/>
<br/>
<button type="Submit" value="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out! In `forms.py`, my `RegistrationForm`'s `email` attribute should read:

```
email = TextField('email', validators=[InputRequired(), Email(), Length(max=25)])
```

I forgot the darn parenthesis for the `Email` parameter.